# Crash when trying to update the UI on a previous view controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

Alright I have view controller A that presents view controller B like so...

```
@IBAction func presentView(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle:nil)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Popout") as! PopoutWindow
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    self.present(vc, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

When I'm done with view controller B, I dismiss it like so...

```
let vc = WellnessPlanEnrollmentController()
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
vc.refreshView()
})
```

And then the function I'm calling is attempting to update my UI with the new data from view controller B. However, when I reload the first view, I get a weird crash saying that my label I'm trying to update is nil.

```
func refreshView() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self._petNameLabel.text = self.object.name
        // crashes here because my label is nil???????
    }
}
```

Error: `FirstViewController.swift:128: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

I feel like it's because the view is not in focus when I'm calling the function but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please show the actual error log rather than your own version of it.

Comment: Oh… what is WellnessPlanEnrollmentController? Is that your “view controller A”? Because I don’t think that’s working like you think it is. In your code you are creating a BRAND NEW view controller. You are not accessing the view controller that already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is failing because you create a new instance of `WellnessPlanEnrollmentController`. This instance is not connected to any Storyboard or View so all of its outlets are nil.

Possible solution:

Create a delegate in your controller `B` and assign it before presenting and call it after dismiss.